# OCZ Vertex 4 64 GB timeouts on Areca 1880IX-16-4G

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-5, hardware-raid

I use 3x OCZ Vertex 4 64 GB in RAID5. If they work then it's all ok, but suddenly random drives are dropped from array with timeout errors. Sometimes even two of them which causes filesystem errors.

I've replaced the cable, the backplane, but nothing helps. SMART on disks are fine.

The RAID card has the latest firmware.

How do I fix that ?

Comment: Do these drivers support Time-Limited Error Recovery (TLER)?

Comment: I don't know. I've set TLER to 5 seconds inside RAID controller settings.

Comment: 5 seconds is really short amount of time....Use the appropriate tools to determine is the drives support this feature

Comment: There are only such options: 5, 6, 7 or disabled. So far working good on 5 ;)

Comment: I thought you were getting timeouts at 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I've switched from RAID5 to RAID3 which resolved this problem ;)